# Comparing values in two files using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm doing my own projects to attempt to learn bash more, especially awk, and I've become stuck on something in regards to multi-file input in bash. I'm attempting to write a script that takes the inputs of three columns in `file1.txt`. If any names in `file2.txt` match anything in column 11 of `file1.txt` then do a certain command.
File1.txt sample contents (only showing columns 8, 9, 10, 11):

```
September   23    12pm   Banana 
December    1     1am    Pineapple
May         28    7pm    Apple
```

File2.txt sample contents:

```
Grapefruit
Apple
Lemon
Banana
```

The command would be in regards to comparing the dates to the system clock, but I do not want to get ahead of myself (I believe converting the dates into epoch time would be the way to go). Currently this is what I came up with:

```
awk '{Dates[$1]=$8, $9, $10, $11 FS Names[$2]=$1;next} {a[$1, $2]} {print Dates[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I'm aware that this is lacking severely. I hope I'm at least heading in the right direction.

Comment: You're missing the `FNR==NR` test to detect whether you're processing `file1.txt` or `file2.txt`.

Comment: What is `{a[$1, $2]}` supposed to do?

Comment: Is `Dates[$1]=$8, $9, $10, $11 FS Names[$2]=$1` supposed to be 2 assignments? Separate them with `;`, not `FS`.

Comment: If you're only going to show 4 columns of data (wise), then adjust the description to refer to column 4, not column 11.  It makes it easier for those trying to help you.  Say that you'd like to print the data from `file1.txt` if column 4 matches a line from `file2.txt`.  You might then find it better to list the files in the order `file2.txt file1.txt` and read the values from `file2.txt` first, and then print the lines from `file1.txt` when column 4 (11) matches.

Answer (score 2):

Your description of what you are attempting is a bit vague, but if I understand you want to find the dates in `file1.txt` where the fourth field is also contained as field one in `file2.txt`. Your approach with using arrays is the right approach, but if you are attempting to do what I've described above, you want to read `file2.txt` first and then process the records in `file1.txt`.

In doing so, you want to get the time as a number removing the `am` or `pm` that is attached to the third field. You can do that in awk simply by adding `0` to the field value to tell awk to interpret the field as a number (non-numeric suffixes will be discarded)

Putting that together, and using `f1` for `file1.txt` and `f2` for `file2.txt` and processing the data you posted and not some other file with more fields, you could do:

```bash
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=1; next} $4 in a {print $1, $2, $3+0}' f2 f1
```

(note how `file2.txt` is processed before `file1.txt`, e.g. `f2` and `f1` respectively)

Where are records in `file2.txt` (`f2` above) are processing into the `a[]` array indexed by the field value itself. `FNR == NR` is a simple conditional that says while the file-record-number (`FNR`) is equal to the number of records (`NR`) meaning that applies to the first file processed (`FNR` resets to `1` for each new file, `NR` continues sequentially). So the array is only filled with records from the first file processed (`file2.txt`).

The test `$4 in a` simply tests if the value of field four is found as an index in the `a[]` array. You can then process the date/time using the corresponding field numbers, `1 - 3` in the data you posted, adding `+0` to the third field to interpret as a number.

**Output**

That will isolate the dates/times matching the two records in `file2.txt` that also appear in `file1.txt`, e.g.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=1; next} $4 in a {print $1, $2, $3+0}' f2 f1
September 23 12
May 28 7
```

With the dates and times separated, you can use a `printf()` call in awk to form the date into a format that can be converted to epoch. If using GNU awk or mawk, there are time and date extensions that handle converting from a datespec (normal month day year time) into a timespec (seconds since epoch), see, e.g. [GNU Awk User's Guide - 9.1.5 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions). For the month/number (e.g. `1 - 12`) conversion you can create a simple array of months in the `BEGIN` section to use as a lookup table.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question or if you have further questions and I can help further.

Comment: side note : `mawk-1`'s implementation of `strftime()` suffers from year-2038 limit issue, while empiricial evidence suggests `gawk`'s `%s` formatter stops functioning properly when negative epochs is older than `1900 01 01 00:00:00 | -2208970800 | 01/01/00 00:00:00` (but other time formatting letters continue to function properly, just that `%s` returns `-1` instead : `1899 12 31 23:59:59 | -1 | 12/31/99 23:59:59`

Comment: side note 2 : although hardly of concern to anyone, `gawk` appears to have a hard-coded year limit of less than `2^31 + 1900`